# Como obtener el código de país del número ingresado para autentificarse en mi app en android?

Tags: android-studio, firebase

Estoy creando una app en android+firebase y para autentificarse uso el numero de teléfono que ingresa el usuario y quiero que se detecte automaticamente a que pais pertenece el numero ingresado y sacar el codigo de pais para enviarselo al servidor, este envie el sms de verificacion. gracias anticipadamente

```
   PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
            "+591"+num,60, TimeUnit.SECONDS,
            LogPhone.this,
            new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {
                @Override
                public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
                    signInWithCredential(phoneAuthCredential);
                }
                @Override
                public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Número Incorrecto "+numero.getText()+" Error:"+e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                public void onCodeSent(String VerificatedId, PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken forceResendingToken){
                    super.onCodeSent(VerificatedId, forceResendingToken);
                    LoadingPhone.dismiss();
                    mVerificatedId=VerificatedId;
                    Intent VCode=new Intent(LogPhone.this, VerificCode.class);
                    VCode.putExtra("ID",mVerificatedId);
                    startActivity(VCode);
                    finish();
                }
                @Override
                public void onCodeAutoRetrievalTimeOut(String s) {
                    super.onCodeAutoRetrievalTimeOut(s);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Time Out Function ",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
    );
```

Comment: ¿Que has intentado? ¿Has pensado algo ya? Por favor, lee el [tour] para ver como funciona el sitio y [ask] para realizar una pregunta de calidad y que te podamos ayudar

Comment: el código en este caso lo añado manualmente (+591 Bolivia) pero quiero que este código se reconozca automáticamente al saber el numero ingresado